# spring batch calling stored procedure

Tags: java, spring, stored-procedures, spring-batch, spring-jdbc

I am writing a Spring batch application to:

1. To `read` multiple csv file data
2. do some `process` to the data
3. then `write` to the sql server database

I have a stored procedure that takes the input data, price, close of business date and security id. The procedure `UPDATE` if record exists already and if not does an `INSERT`.

I would like to call this stored procedure in my `insert()` method see below:

```
@Slf4j
public class PriceWriter implements ItemWriter<Price> {


    private final PriceDAO pd;

    public PriceDAO(PriceDAO pd) {
        this.pd = pd;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends Price> items) throws Exception {
        log.info("Ready to write {} items " + items.size());
        pd.insert(items);
    }
}



@Repository
public class PriceDAOImpl implements PriceDAO {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    public void insert(List<? extends Price> prices) {
        prices.forEach(e -> {
            System.out.println("Calling Stored Procedure For Records:  " + e.toString());
        });
    }
}
```

examples I have seen are all `INSERT` statements and have not come across any where stored proc is being called in the context of `ItemWriter` `write()`.

How should I call my stored procedure in `insert()` method or is there another way I should be calling stored procedure in a Spring batch application? Can someone demonstrate how and with an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can do whatever you like to call stored procedure to store the data. There is no ItemWriter that can do this but, you can follow two approaches:

- Direclty call your SP in writer
- Implement a service, having your mapping for SP and call it.